# Nested display:table-row in a display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am having some issue with html nested display:table-row in a display:table-cell. I am trying to nest few table-row inside a table-cell.

Here is a [html structure](https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/z5ah1s50/1/) to illustrate the issue:

```css
body
{
     background-color:#6699cc;
}
.row1
{
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    font-family: 'MS sans serif, Fallback, sans-serif';
    
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
.row1_cell1
{
    width:20%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid DarkBlue;
}
.row1_cell1 img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.row1_cell2
{
    width:80%;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #F6F934;
}
.row1_cell2_subrow{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%
    border:3px solid red;
}
.subrow_cell1{
    display:table-cell;
    width:60%;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.subrow_cell2{
    display:table-cell;
    width:40%;
    text-align:right;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
    <div class="row1_cell1">
        <img class="row1_cell1_image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="row1_cell2">
        <div class="row1_cell2_subrow">
            <div class="subrow_cell1">subrow1_cell1</div>
            <div class="subrow_cell2">subrow1_cell2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row1_cell2_subrow">
            <div class="subrow_cell1">subrow2_cell1</div>
            <div class="subrow_cell2">subrow2_cell2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is that "div" with class "row1_cell2_subrow" doesn't occupy 100% width of its parent? And how comes its border is not showing either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be valid, your nesting needs to follow this form:

```
table > table-row > table-cell > table > table-row > table-cell
```

In other words:

- An element of display:table-cell should only be nested directly inside of an element of display:table-row.
- An element of display:table-row should only be nested directly inside of an element of display:table

So, it is valid to place an element of display:table directly inside of an element of display:table-cell. But it is NOT valid to have an element of display:table-row directly inside of an element of display:table-cell.

Comment: just made some modifications according to your suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/z5ah1s50/2/. The border that div(".row1_cell2_subrow") is still not showing. But at least, the layout seems to be right now. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Try changing the word "border" to "outline" and see what it does.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/z5ah1s50/4/ , still not showing. Never mind, those borders are only for debugging for my case.